# How would I change a button's text when it's hovered over using css?

Tags: html, css

I am working on a follower system for my website.  When the user visits another user's page, they should have the option to follow or unfollow depending on the situation.

If the current user (user1) is following the other user (user2), I would like to display "Following" at the top of the page.  If user1 were to hover over the text that says "Following" the text should change to "unfollow" indicating if they click the button, user1 will unfollow user2.  What's the best way to do this?  Should I be using a button or a link that runs a function on another page.  Thank you.

Comment: This is bad UI design anyway, since in this mobile world there is no such thing as "hovering over the text".

Comment: The best way to do this, is to have a confirmation action after clicking the button that will inform the user they are about to un-follow.

Comment: Wow, thank you all for the feedback.  I think a confirmation action would be a great fix for mobile users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This prototype should demonstrate how I achieved this effect.

https://codepen.io/JimmyJames88/pen/ymjpMg

Mobile browsers may vary in how they handle :hover

Sidenote - You may want to set a fixed width on the button to keep it from changing size when you hover.

```
<div class="follow-button">
  <span>Following</span>
  <span>Unfollow</span>
</div>
```

```
.follow-button {
  background-color: #333;
  color: #FFF;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 1rem;
  border-radius: 3px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.follow-button > span:nth-child(2),
.follow-button:hover > span:nth-child(1) {
  display: none;
}

.follow-button:hover > span:nth-child(2) {
  display: inline;
}
```

Basically, we place both "states" inside of a span, and only display one of these spans at a time.

Comment: Of course, screen-readers may read this as a very confusing "FollowingUnfollow" jumble.

Comment: You're not wrong, but I thought it was important to offer a working solution that is palatable to a junior developer ;)

Comment: Thank you for the demo, and thank you taking the time to help out a junior developer : )

Answer (score 3):

It's pretty difficult to do this dynamically but you could easily swap between two preset text values by using a `CSS pseudo-class`.

Basically, the text is added as `data-attribute` then swapped out. BUT you also need to make sure there's "default" text for screen readers.

```css
button {
 font-size: 20px;
 padding: 10px 20px;
}

button span {
  display:none;
}

button:after {
  content: attr(data-btnText); 
}

button:hover:after {
  content: attr(data-btnHoverText);
}
```

```html
<button data-btnText="text 1" data-btnHoverText="other text"><span>text 1</span></button>
```

But as others have said, this isn't a great UX pattern.

Comment: Groovy, I did not realize you could access attribute values like this in CSS!

Comment: I see, thank you for your feedback.  This will help me a lot.